# What is the weight limit of an average shower head pipe?

Tags: shower, pipe

I want to use a bucket of filtered water for showering. The bucket when full weighs 20 lbs. Would hanging this bucket on my shower head pipe which is coming out of the wall damage the piping?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear due to lack of information. However, I'd expect any all-metal plumbing assembly to hold 20 pounds near the wall. With the load cantilevered out even a few inches the torque gets large in a hurry.

Comment: The cheap/lame imported chrome plated shower arms at the "big box" are very thin. If you want to do this I recommend removing the shower arm and replacing it with a thick-walled sch. 40 brass nipple. This is assuming that the in-wall piping can support the load, as mentioned by @ed beal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mom used to bring well water back from the lakehouse for rinsing her hair; installed a shelf for those blue 5 gallon water jugs, which weigh ~40 pounds.

It seems you have a 2.5 gallon bucket, with a handle that will put the weight out at least a few inches (more like half a foot, plus). **I would not do this.** Perhaps a hook in the ceiling or on the wall?

If you do break it, you're looking at tearing open the wall.

Comment: I've been told that even the in-shower shelving systems which hook over the pipe at a Bad Idea. Copper pipe is noit remarkably strong and this wasn't intended to support more than the shower head itself.I would _definitely_ recommend a hook driven into a ceiling joist at an absolute minimum. Besides, that would let you mount a pulley system to make raising the full bucket easier. "A pint's a pound the world around" and a liter is a kilogram; it adds up fast.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say without opening the wall you may have a metal pipe coming out of the wall and PVC or CPVC, copper or Galvanized pipe. With galvanized pipe it might be strong enough if the pipe is strapped to a stud but you would be taking a chance.